# ACF and PACF in Box Jenkins

Tags: box-jenkins

guys!

I know this might be a silly question, but I am really curios if my interpretation is correct. I have some stock returns and try to fit and ARMA model I took the log difference and I want now to identify the ARMA order. The ACF and PACF are included in the photo below. There is just one spike at 0 lags (as expected) and nothing else seems to be significant. Does this mean that a ARMA(0,1,0) is the suitable model (a random walk model?).

Thank you!

[image]

Comment: how large is your sample?

Comment: 59 monthly observations

Comment: With such a small sample I wouldn't pay attention to long lags. In your case there's no evidence of autocorrelation. That's what you'd expect in stock returns. run ACf and PACF of abs values of returns, it;s more interesting

Comment: Aksakal That's pretty much an answer, if you want to post it (if you can perhaps add a teeny bit more detail that'd be good, but I think it would do even as as is)